# Internet-Explorer won't get closed after my module ends

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, userform

I have this macro that pulls out data from a website. I get the inputs from a user-from. It works with no error but IE won't close and sucks up all of the memory. Is something else needed rather than `IE.Quit`?

This is the sub. As you can see I close IE at the end.

```
Public Cancel As Boolean

Sub USGD()

Dim IE As Object
Dim iWsh As Worksheet
Dim link As String
Dim sDate As String
Dim eDate As String
Dim StationID As String
    
Cancel = False

With USGS
    .StartUpPosition = 0
    .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
    .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
    .Show
End With

If Cancel = True Then
    Unload USGS
    Exit Sub
End If

With ActiveWorkbook
    Set iWsh = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
End With

iWsh.Activate
iWsh.Range("A1").Select 'I know this is not efficient but works fine


 StationID = USGS.TextBox1.Text
'StationID = InputBox("Please enter the station ID")
    
'sDate = InputBox("Please enter START date in this format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'")
'eDate = InputBox("Please enter END date in this format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'")
 sDate = Format(USGS.TextBox2.Text, "yyyy-mm-dd")
 eDate = Format(USGS.TextBox3.Text, "yyyy-mm-dd")
 
 
link = "https://waterdata.usgs.gov/ & _ 
StationID & sDate & eDate
 
 
 Unload USGS
 
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
           .Visible = False
           .Navigate link 'URL
           
  Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  
           .ExecWB 17, 0 '// SelectAll
           .ExecWB 12, 2 '// Copy selection
End With
     

    iWsh.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    Range("A1").Select
    
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set iWsh = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

And this is the user-form: **I didn't have this problem while using Input-Box so I am guessing, it has something to do with the user-form. This only happens when user closes the user-form.**

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
Me.Hide
    Cancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub OK_Click()
Me.Hide
End Sub
```

**Note:** If the user cancel, it would not even open the IE and exits the sub right after.

**But** if user closes the form, it does open IE, and doesn't set the `Cancel` to be True which is the condition to exit the sub.

**Update:** [Expert-Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26271904/Kill-accumulate-un-used-IE-process-in-VBA.html) covered the issue but never came up with an actual solution.

**Update-2:** Closing all instances of IE is not an option.

This is how user-form is set up now:

[image]

Comment: I have seen somewhere that somebody had `IE.Quit` two times in two consecutive lines. It looked strange to me but let me know if that's the solution.

Comment: I just ran a quick test on this and there shouldn't be any issues with using `.Quit`. My best guess about the double `IE.Quit` in other cases is that IE (from limited testing) does create two processes. It properly closes both out on the first `.Quit` though. I wasnt able to find a way to force the IE process to hang on though.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. @BrandonBarney If you check out the link you'd get some useful info from it. About two instances of IE as well.

Comment: [This sledge hammer](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/229394-close-all-ie-browser-windows-visual-basic-applications.html) may give you an idea on how to do a workaround for this matter

Comment: see their help documentation for automated retrievals... https://help.waterdata.usgs.gov/faq/automated-retrievals.... frozen tabs in IE is usually associated with misbehaving third-party addons.... perform an manual extraction (by entering the station id and start and end dates yourself) with IE running in noAddons Mode... if it works in noAddons mode, the problem is one of your addons in IE. Manually stepping through the process flow allows you to also use the dev tool to see if there are beforeunload event handlers which is preventing the automated IE instance from Quitting.

Comment: Start>Control Panel>Administrative tools>Event Viewer>Windows Components..... will list application event errors that have been caused by misbehaving addons. The 'Faulting' module will give you a hint as to which one....

Comment: also... Internet Options>Advanced tab, uncheck "Do not save encrypted files to disk"....

Comment: @Sgdva thanks. I know how to implement that. That's not desired as I am writing this as an add-on which my colleagues will use and I cannot close all of the IE windows.

Comment: @RobParsons Thanks. First two comments of yours about add-ons may not be my case as I am pretty sure I have no special add-on for IE but will check it. Also will give the third one a try.

Comment: If you have used your script successfully in the past... then it is likely that the web site has made changes and may be using the onbeforeunload event handler or possibly you have also changed IE settings....Tabbed browsing settings, uncheck "warn me when closing multiple tabs"

Comment: @RobParsons I've been using it but with `InputBox`. It can be something triggered by `UserForm`.

Comment: Set your `IE.Visble = True` and see if that provides any hints. It's possible there's an open dialog waiting for user input?

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks for your advice. I already did that. The IE window closes at the end or even doesn't show up but it is there in the processing applications.

Comment: What type of control are ToggleButton1 and OK?

Comment: And what are you attempting to do with the variable `Cancel`? Are there any other event-handlers on the USGS form?

Comment: @DavidZemens With `Cancel` I am trying to exit the sub if the user decided to close the user-form (pushing ToggleButton1, x at the top-right). Both of these are push buttons.

Comment: CommandButton? Or ToggleButton? These are different type of control. No such thing as a "push" button :)

Comment: @DavidZemens OK is command button. ToggleButton1 is the closing button, x at the top-right, and I am assuming it is toggle button (is name?) but cannot check it. Push Button was versus radio button. I am sorry that it wasn't a technical term. Not using user-forms that much.

Comment: no worries, I'm trying to replicate the error on my end so making sure I set up the form in the same way.

Comment: @DavidZemens thanks I updated my question and added an answer which may give you some more info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143513/discussion-between-david-zemens-and-masoud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I am unable to replicate the error, so there are two things you should try:

1. Reboot your computer and verify the error continues. If not, problem solved.
2. Recreate the UserForm & code in a *new, blank* workbook, and see if the error continues. If not, problem solved.

(Sometimes Workbooks, and/or UserForms become corrupted)

I also re-factored the code a little bit, which you might consider *even if* one of the above suggestions solves the problem. It just cleans it up a little bit and makes it more purposeful.

## In a standard module, place the following code:

The `USGD` procedure displays the userform and unloads it. A separate procedure named `GetData` will do the work in IE and add the worksheet, etc.  The `GetData` procedure is only executed if the user clicks on the "OK" button on the form. Therefore, the "X"/cancel button will allow the user to close the form.

```
Option Explicit

Sub USGD()
'Procedure displays the userform for the user
Dim USGSForm As New USGS
With USGSForm
    .StartUpPosition = 0
    .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
    .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
    .Show
End With
Unload USGSForm
End Sub

Sub GetData(StationID As String, sDate As String, eDate As String)
'This procedure queries the InternetExplorer for the values from UserForm
Dim iWsh As Worksheet
Dim link As String
Dim IE As Object

sDate = Format(sDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
eDate = Format(eDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")

link = "https://waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/dv?cb_00060=on&format=rdb&site_no=" & _
    StationID & "&referred_module=sw&period=&begin_date=" & sDate & "&end_date=" & eDate

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = False
    .Navigate link 'URL
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    .ExecWB 17, 0 '// SelectAll
    .ExecWB 12, 2 '// Copy selection
    .Quit
End With

With ActiveWorkbook
    Set iWsh = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
End With
iWsh.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Application.GoTo iWsh.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

## In your UserForm module, place the following code:

This is the code for the "OK" button, which takes the values from TextBoxes on the form and sends those to the `GetData` procedure. Note the `Select Case` logic which will exit the procedure early if *any* of the parameters are empty, so it will *not* call `GetData`.

```
Private Sub OK_Click()
    Dim id As String, sDate As String, eDate As String
    'Get values from the form
    id = Me.TextBox1.Value
    sDate = Me.TextBox2.Value
    eDate = Me.TextBox3.Value
    'Hide the form
    Me.Hide

    'If ANY required parameter is blank, this results in malformed URL so exit the procedure
    Select Case vbNullString
        Case id, sDate, eDate
            MsgBox "You left some parameter blank, no query will be performed.", vbInformation
            GoTo EarlyExit
        Case Else
            'Send values to the procedure that queries IE
            Call GetData(id, sDate, eDate)
    End Select

EarlyExit:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround but **not a good answer**. Also, does not explain why that happens.

I changed my user-form so the user cannot close it. Also set the initial value of `Cancel` to be True

`Cancel = True`

and when the use pushes *OK* it will be set to false. Look below for the user form code:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub OK_Click()
    Me.Hide
    Cancel = False
End Sub
```

Obvious downside of this is that users cannot close the user-form; they have to hit *OK*. This won't cause an error. I just can add a condition that if one of the text boxes was empty then exit the sub. Something like below;

```
If sDate = "" Or eDate = "" Or StationID = "" Then GoTo 92
'. Rest of ...
'. My ... 
'. Code ...
92:
           Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: **You really needed to handle the queryClose event of the Userform**. This is might be good reading for Userform handling: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5351/user-forms/19037/handling-queryclose#t=201705302136167547879

Comment: @MacroMarc Thanks. By that time it was the first time I was using UserForms. I ended up writing a script with completely different structure. Thanks for pointing to the documentation tho.